# Toolbar setNavigationOnClickListener doesnt work / gets ignored

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my app, there is an activity which needs to be closed on navigation click. In the past, the code below worked perfectly, however, since the new Android changes it doesnt work anymore.

**Are there new ways to call the Navigation icon click? Is there something i am missing?**

`ActivitySettings.kt`

```
class ActivitySettings : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binder: ActivitySettingsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binder = ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        binder.topToolbarBack.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topToolbarBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/white_material"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_outline_arrow_back_24"
        app:popupTheme="@style/popupMenuThemeDark"
        app:title="@string/currentScreenSettings"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white_material" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topToolbarBack" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ```lifecycleowner``` doesnt seem to exist, getting an unresolved reference

Comment: Just read what you sent, and for what i need to do, i really dont need this. Its just a toolbar, why would i need to use a data binding layout when I just need a binder for the toolbar itself?

Comment: Your `RecyclerView` is covering your toolbar. You need to constraint the `RecyclerView` to be below the `Toolbar`, in order `RecyclerView` not to steal touch events.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski its not, the recyclerview is respectively under the toolbar. It is not covering the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the way the layouts got called.

`binder` can be considered a "secondary layout". Since in that activity, i set as ContenteView `R.layout.activity_settings`, the binder, that can still get the elements from the layout, gets basically covered by the layout currently set.

If you want to use `binder` you must set as inside `setContentView()` `binder.root`, which loads the proper layout you need.

So, the code fixed is:

```
class ActivitySettings : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binder: ActivitySettingsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binder = ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binder.root)

        binder.topToolbarBack.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you call `setSupportActionBar(binder.topToolbarBack)` before you set click listener for the toolbar

Comment: I just tried and it doesnt work. I have found a solution though, let me write it down